# Can't connect to ESP32 serial on custom PCB (Schematic, Photo included)

Tags: esp32

I have experience with ESP32 Dev board but this is first time with custom PCB.
I connected RX-TX, TX-RX. ESP32 got 3.3V stable. boot-press-hold-reset-press-release.
But I got `Invalid head of packet` or `No serial data received.`

Is it problem with the schematic or PCB layout? How can I fix / debug this?

[image: schematic1]
[image: schematic2]]
[image: pcb]]
[image: photo]]

Comment: Can you use a simple serial communications program (“terminal emulator”) to see if there is any output from the board on reset? Have you tried switching RX/TX? Also you are missing a common ground…

Comment: Thank you. I connect the ground, tried switching RX/TX, and check the output with the reset button pressed. But got no output. (I got output with other dev board, so setup seems to correct)

Comment: I checked the voltage of the input capacitor with a multimeter, and it is solid 3.3v.
So it is definitely powered. Do you think the reset/boot button can be a problem? I copied it from https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good point. Do you know a good way to test it right away? Like solder EN(exposed on the button) - Resistor - onboard 3.3V test point or capacitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the EN line is missing a pull-up.

The principle is that it should be pulled high for normal operation, and pulled low (via the reset button) for reset.

The resistor is visible as R1 on page 24 of the [ESP32-PICO-MINI-02 datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-mini-02_datasheet_en.pdf), or as R11 on the [schematic you linked to in comments](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf), which is for different models of the ESP32 modules.

Also, unrelated: you should read Espressif's [Hardware Design Guidelines](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf), especially section 3.1.2. I don't think the module's antenna over a ground plane (or whatever all that copper is on the part of the PCB beyond the gap) is a good idea. The [PCB Design and Module placement guide](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp-wroom-02_pcb_design_and_module_placement_guide_0.pdf) has more information on the topic. Basically you should never have any copper trace under the antenna, and maintain a clearance around it.