# What is correct schematic to use ESP-PROG?

Tags: esp32

I failed to program my custom ESP32 board because I am missing a pull-up in the EN pin.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/671905/341562

I am planning to re-order the PCB with the fix, but I am just curious if I can just forget about the pull-up, remove reset and boot buttons, and just directly expose [6 pins](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/espressif-esp-dev-kits/en/latest/other/esp-prog/user_guide.html#program-interface) from ESP32 module.

Will this be a problem? It seems to be straight-forward but I just want to make sure.
Thank you.

Comment: The data sheet says that you cannot leave the enable floating. Took me 2 minutes to find the info.

Comment: @RussellH You are right. Thank you for the help. Appreciated.

Comment: On some ESP32 boards I use this 6 pin idea, but I add the typical circuit with two NPN and resistors around to the board (PUMH4,115 in SOT363 case). This way I do not expose EN and I00 directly to the connector, but RTS and DTR inputs. To program such a board, I can use standard USB to TTL serial adapters as long as they provide RTS and DTR.

Comment: @Jens I see. Thank you.

Comment: I can’t see how adding a pull-up resistor would be difficult. So simple that I would probably not consider redoing the pcb. In the olden days it was common to do semi- major rework with adding components ,wires and cutting tracks. Even in military equipment.